# Laptop abruptly turns itself off when battery plugged out

Tags: battery, thinkpad

I recently realized that my x270 probably shouldn't suddenly turn itself off when its external battery is taken out. I remember being able to switch batteries while it was turned out in the previous model (x260). **The internal battery works fine - I can start my laptop using it as the only driver**, it's not disabled via BIOS.

Is that expected behavior, something they changed in x270? If not, what could be the reason it doesn't work as expected?

Comment: Are you sure the x270 has an internal battery and an removable battery?  That would be very unusual.

Comment: Thanks for the question! I hopefully clarified it by highlighting the part about the internal battery keeping the laptop up when there's no external one.

Answer (score 1):

The ThinkPad X270 has an *optional* internal battery.

[TP X270 Specifications](https://psref.lenovo.com/syspool/Sys/PDF/ThinkPad/ThinkPad_X270/ThinkPad_X270_Spec.PDF)

See right hand side battery description.

> Internal battery Optional: Integrated Li-ion or Li-Polymer 3-cell (23Wh)
>
> External battery Li-ion 3-cell (23Wh) or 6-cell (48Wh or 72Wh)

It appears your computer may not have the internal battery. It would remain charged to some extent and active whenever the computer was plugged in.

If you do actually have the internal battery, and the laptop shuts down when removing the external battery, then your computer needs service to correct a hardware error inside the laptop.

Comment: Thanks for the question! I hopefully clarified things by highlighting the part about the internal battery keeping the laptop up when there's no external one.

Comment: I thought the highlighted part was about a different computer (X260) and not the X270.  You said the X270 shut off when removing the battery.

Comment: Laptop does shut off when the battery is in and I remove it, but it lets me start when there's no external battery.

Comment: That now indicates a hardware error in the circuit allowing a battery to be remove. I did amend my answer to allow for this.

Comment: Thanks, I like this theory! I wonder if a BIOS change can fix that - definitely something I should try out.

Comment: Try the BIOS update but I think this is more likely a hardware issue. The original BIOS would have handled the batteries.

Comment: Unfortunately it looks like you were right. I updated the BIOS and it didn't help.

Comment: So you need to get it serviced. You might wish to acknowledge my answer.